# Which is the right function to call in a jsp page to verify the logged user is in role

Tags: jsp, jstl, azure-web-roles

I'm looking for the function to verify if the user logged belongs to a role. is maybe the following?

```
pageContext.request.userPrincipal.roles
```

How should I use it properly along with JSTL to test if the user belong to ADMIN group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Method expression '**pageContext.request.isUserInRole**' in JSP to check whether the current authenticated user has a role.

**Test this:**

```
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}">

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}">

        User ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} in ADMIN Group

    </c:if>

</c:if>
```

**Notes**:

- Make sure you have a JSTL Core Tags taglib directive on the top of your JSP file:

> <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

- Calling a method with/without parameters in EL expression is only supported from JavaEE6 (JSP 2.2 & EL 2.2).