# Type of pageContext.request

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24172005/4624905) answer very usefull but I can't figure out why it works.

In accordance with [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) pageContext getRequest() method returns ServletRequest and it doesn't contain getUserPrincipal() method. So why do things like this work

```
<c:if test="${not empty pageContext.request.userPrincipal}">

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}">

        User ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} in ADMIN Group

    </c:if>

</c:if>
```

Is there implicit type conversion or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet API has been designed, a long time ago, in order to be usable in a context that is different from a web, HTTP context (I think supporting [WAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol) using this API was a goal, at that time).

In reality, I don't know of any context other that the traditional Java EE webapp context where the servlet API is used. And in that context, all requests are instances of HttpServletRequest (which is a sub-interface of ServletRequest). And [this method exists in HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29).

Comment: But why does it work? If pageContext.request returns ServletRequest in java you cannot use method of its subclass if you don't cast it to HttpServletRequest excplicity.

Comment: That would be true in Java. But the code you posted is not Java. It's the JSP expression language, which is a much more dynamic language. If a `getFoo()` getter method is available on an object `bar`, the `bar.foo` EL expression calls that getter, using reflection, without caring of the type of the object.

Comment: Oh now I get it. I didn't know that EL uses reflection. Thanks :)